# In group theory, is it true that $f(X \vee Y) = f(X) \vee f(Y)$?

Tags: group-theory

($\vee$ denotes [join](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Join_of_subgroups)).

Let $G$ and $H$ denote Abelian groups, $X$ and $Y$ denote subalgebras of $G$, and let $f : G \rightarrow H$ denote a homomorphism. Then:

$$f(X \vee Y) = f(X+Y) = f(X)+f(Y) = f(X) \vee f(Y)$$

So $f(X \vee Y) = f(X) \vee f(Y)$.

Now suppose we relax our conditions, so that $G$ and $H$ are no longer assumed Abelian.

> **Question.** Is it still provable that $f(X \vee Y) = f(X) \vee f(Y)$?

Comment: Um, I still don't where thing went wrong if you simply directly adapt the proof for abelian case to general case...

Comment: @Gina, in general group theory, all we know is that $XY \subseteq X \vee Y$. In particular, there is no guarantee that $XY$ is a group.

Comment: Oh no, that's not what I meant, of course we are not going to just replace that with $XY$. No I meant instead of $X+Y$ we use $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(XY)^{n}$.

Comment: @Gina, I think that's a proof.

Comment: By subalgebra, do you mean subgroup?

Comment: @Bryan, yes. $\,\!$

Comment: I think the best view on $X\vee Y$ is the following: Let $X\xrightarrow{i_1}G$, $Y\xrightarrow{i_2}G$ the inclusions of the subgroups. Let $X\sqcup Y\xrightarrow{u}G$ be the arrow induced by the coproduct. Then $X\vee Y$ is the image of $u$, i.e. the universal monomorphism $u$ factors through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That we have $f(X\vee Y)\subseteq f(X)\vee f(Y)$ should be clear (the image of a product of elements in $X$ or $Y$ is a product of elements in $f(X)$ or $f(Y)$).

For the other direction, let $g\in f(X)\vee f(Y)$. Then $g=g_1\cdot\cdots\cdot g_n$ where $g_i\in f(X)$ or $g_i\in f(Y)$. Thus each $g_i$ is of the form $f(x_i)$ where $x_i\in X$ or $x_i\in Y$. Thus we can rewrite $g=f(x_1\cdot\cdots\cdot x_n)$. Thus $g\in f(X\vee Y)$.

This approach can be generalized for arbitrary collections of subgroups since it didn't matter that $\{X,Y\}$ was a finite collection. The only thing that was important was that elements were a finite product of other elements. Thus for any collection of subgroups $\cal S$ of $G$, we have that $f(\bigvee_{S\in\cal S} S)=\bigvee_{S\in\cal S}f(S)$.

The dual question is however false. In general, we do not have that $f(X\wedge Y)=f(X)\wedge f(Y)$ for arbitrary subgroups $X$ and $Y$, specifically the inclusion $f(X)\wedge f(Y)\leq f(X\wedge Y)$ need not hold (the other inclusion always holds). I was having trouble finding a counterexample, so I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878043/homomorphic-image-of-intersection-equals-intersection-of-homomorphic-images?lq=1) where Marcin Łoś gave a counterexample in the comments. Thus in general, a group homomorphism does *not* induce a lattice homomorphism between the subgroup lattices.

However, if $f$ is a quotient map (or surjective by the 1st isomorphism theorem), the [4th isomorphism theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourthGroupIsomorphismTheorem.html) does give us some relation between subgroup intersections.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I see it (without reference to "messy" product representations).

If we partially order the lattice of subgroups of $G$ by inclusion, then $H \vee K = \langle H,K\rangle$, the subgroup generated by the set $H \cup K$. By definition this is the smallest subgroup (via our partial order) of $G$ that contains both $H$ and $K$.

Now for any function $f:A \to B$, if $X \subseteq Y \subseteq A$, we certainly have: $f(X) \subseteq f(Y)$.

Homomorphisms are functions, so we have $f(H) \subseteq f(\langle H,K\rangle)$, and similarly for $f(K)$ (since $H,K \subseteq \langle H,K\rangle$).

This shows that $\langle f(H),f(K)\rangle \subseteq f(\langle H,K\rangle)$, by minimality (there is a "hidden appeal" here to the fact $f$ is a homomorphism, so we may conclude $f(\langle H,K\rangle)$ is a group, as our property of "smallest subgroup that contains the generating set" only applies to elements of the subgroup lattice, not arbitrary subsets of $f(G)$).

Now suppose $L$ is ANY subgroup of $f(G)$ containing $f(H)$ and $f(K)$. It follows that $f^{-1}(L)$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $H$ and $K$ (this is again where we invoke the fact that $f$ is a homomorphism), so:

$\langle H,K\rangle \subseteq f^{-1}(L)$

Thus $f(\langle H,K\rangle) \subseteq f(f^{-1}(L)) = L$.

Since $\langle f(H),f(K)\rangle$ is such a subgroup, we have: $f(\langle H,K\rangle) \subseteq \langle f(H),f(K)\rangle$, and equality is established.