# Homomorphic image of intersection equals intersection of homomorphic images?

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

This is a tangent of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877582/in-group-theory-is-it-true-that-fx-vee-y-fx-vee-fy/877606#877606). I wanted to remark in my answer that it is not generally true that given a group homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$ and two subgroups $X,Y\leq G$ that
$$f(X\cap Y)=f(X)\cap f(Y)$$

However, I am having difficulty coming up with a counter-example.

We know it's true that $f(X\cap Y)\subseteq f(X)\cap f(Y)$. So I want two subgroups that don't satisfy $f(X)\cap f(Y)\subseteq f(X\cap Y)$. I cannot have that either $X$ or $Y$ is contained in the kernel of $f$ else I'll have equality. I also cannot have that $X\subseteq Y$ or $Y\subseteq X$. Further, in a finite group, I cannot have that $X$ and $Y$ have coprime order.

The smallest group that gave me subgroups which satisfied these three conditions was $S_3$. But those quotients gave equality. The next were $Q_8$ and $D_8$, but also had no luck. This is becoming tedious.

Any help in coming up with a counter-example (or proving it) is appreciated. Also, outlining other observations that could cut down the computation is appreciated.

Comment: What about something like $f\colon\mathbb{Z}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, $f(a,b)=a+b$, $X=\langle(n,0)\rangle$, $Y=\langle(0,m)\rangle$?

Comment: Ah thank you. That works. Would you make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G = \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ and $H = \Bbb Z_2$ with:

$f: G \to H$ given by $f(a,b) = a$.

Let $X = \{(0,0),(1,0)\}$ and $Y = \{(0,0),(1,1)\}$.

Then $X \cap Y = \{(0,0)\}$ and $f(X \cap Y) = \{0\}$.

Since $f(X) = \{f((0,0)), f((1,0))\} = \{0,1\}$ and

$f(Y) = \{f((0,0),f((1,1))\} = \{0,1\}$, we have:

$f(X) \cap f(Y) = \Bbb Z_2 \neq \{0\} = f(X \cap Y)$.

I believe this is the minimal counter-example.